# I'm trying to add a script as an addon and it does not seem to work

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to use this script: http://sourceforge.net/p/ogreaddons/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/blenderimport/ogre_import.py

To import ogre .Mesh files into blender. However when I drop the script into my addons folder it does not show up on the addons list, nor does it's behavior show up in import. If I try and add addon from file, the same thing happens.

Whats going on here? How do I use this addon? If I can't, what other ways can I import an ogre .mesh file?

Comment: This looks like a Blender 2.49 script.
It will not work with 2.5+ as the python API changed significantly.

Answer (score 4):

The script you link to is written for Blender 2.36, easily identified by looking for registration info.

```
#!BPY

""" Registration info for Blender menus:
Name: 'OGRE (.mesh.xml)...'
Blender: 236
Group: 'Import'
Tip: 'Import an Ogre-Mesh (.mesh.xml) file.'
"""
```

Blender versions above 2.5 won't be able to load this particular script, because internally and externally Blender has changed a lot in the years between Blender 2.36 and the present 2.7+ series.

Your options are:

1. Find an Ogre I/O addon compatible with Blender 2.5 onwards.
   https://bitbucket.org/iboshkov/blender2ogre (compatible with 2.7! )
   This addon seems to be in active development at the time of this writing, that's a good sign.
2. Use an old version of blender, [available from here](http://download.blender.org/release/)